# Email regex compatible with both Ruby and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I use a regex in a model and I use the Judge gem to perform the client side validation, because the judge based its client side validation on the models, it uses the user email regex in both Ruby and javascript.

The problem is that the regex is not javascript compatible, I guess.
So I need to find a regex that is compatible with both Ruby and Javascript, for email validation. (But also for mobile, etc...)

Is there any tool, website or whatever to help me change all my regex?

`/\A\s*(([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})[\s\/,;]*)+\Z/i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here is that javascript doesn't now the `\A\Z` anchors.

If you're not using the `m` flag (multiline), you can replace then with `^$`:

```
/^\s*(([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})[\s\/,;]*)+$/i
```

---

**For reference**, `^$` are anchors matching the beginning and end of the string, except if you use the `m` flag: then they match the beginning and end of a *line*.

`\A\Z` always match beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Does they mean *start* and *end*?

Comment: @Vadorequest: Answer edited, you can also look here for more info if you like: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html